# Creating a custom comparator that does not need to be part of the std::set type

Tags: c++, c++20

I have a custom integer class and I am using this class with `std::set`, so I need to write a comparator.

Every comparator example I have found explicitly includes the comparator:

`std::set<MyCustomClass, MyComparator>`

I would like to avoid explicitly stating the comparator when I create `std::set`.

For `std::unordered_map` we don't need to explicitly state the hash function because we can overload the `std` namespace like this:

```
namespace std                                                      
{                                                                  
    template <>                                                    
    struct hash<MyClass>                                                 
    {                                                              
        size_t operator()(const MyClass m) const                        
        {                                                          
            return std::hash<std::string>()(m.t);
        }                                                          
    };                                                             
}
```

Is it possible to add a member function to my class, or provide an overload for my type in the `std` namespace, so I can declare the `std::set` like this:

`std::set<MyType>`

?

Comment: Just write `operator<` for your class. `std::set<MyCustomClass>` would use that.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you so much. Please put as an answer and I will accept.